# Packaging a BlackBerry (WebWorks) PhoneGap/Cordova application

Tags: blackberry, cordova, packaging, blackberry-webworks

I'm working with PhoneGap/Cordova and the only options I see is to build to the emulator or to build for debuging to the device.

I want to package the app for further distribution and publishing. Any thoughts?

Thanks!!

Comment: I didn't work with PG. What tool are you using. Search there should be `package` somewhere

Comment: Are you using http://build.phonegap.com ?

Comment: No, I already have the sdk and was able to deploy it to the device for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First build with

```
ant blackberry build
```

Then, you need to get and install signing keys:

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/signing_setup_smartphone_apps_1920010_11.html

Then finally, once you are able to code sign you need to use bbwp to sign and package the zip file generated by the build (the zip is in the build directory of the PhoneGap folder). So navigate to your sdk/bin directory and run:

```
bbwp C:\myapp\HelloWorld.zip -g mypassword -o C:\myapp\signed
```

This generates two folders in C:\myapp\signed which contain the signed files. You will need different files depending on the distribution method and a summary is here:

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/distributing_your_app_1866990_11.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That zip is the app for installing in the devices?

Comment: The zip is just the built package that you need to sign with bbwp. If you just want to do a device test you need to have signing set up, be connected to the internet, have the device connected to your computer  and enter "ant blackberry load-device"

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/signing_landing_page.html

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/distributing_your_app_1866990_11.html

You need to get a signing key from RIM in order to publish your apps to the Blackberry App World. My previous experiences was packaging the app with signing key and allow others to install the app with BlackBerry Desktop Manager using the .alx file generated.

Answer (score 0):

cd into the top level directory of your project (the one that contains the www/ folder). Then call this command:

```
ant TARGET build
```

Where TARGET can be blackberry, playbook, or qnx (beta right now). This will create a build/ folder which should contain the needed files for further packaging.