# Want to convert apk to bar file for blackberry 10?

Tags: blackberry-10

I want to convert my phone gap apk to bar for blackberry 10.
I go through this link [Apk to BAR Conversion](http://forums.crackberry.com/bb10-android-app-sideloading-f279/tutorial-run-any-android-2-3-3-app-blackberry10-817781/)

but not able to do this. So please help me on this.

Comment: Here's Blackberry's official docs on it: http://developer.blackberry.com/android/tools/

Here's a site that may do it instantly: http://apk2bar.org/

Have you checked these resources out, yet?

Comment: Do not use apk2bar.org! That is for personal use, if you want to release to BB world you must use your own keys. BlackBerry supports Phonegap, so I suggest you package it directly, [look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152714/packaging-a-blackberry-webworks-phonegap-cordova-application)

Answer (score 0):

What problems/errors did you have?

You can use Command line tools. Here's information about the steps to do it:

[Package Android app to bar](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/preparing_android_apps_for_bbtos_1729415_11.html)